# Anywhere to test what arduino does without the hardware?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

We have this group project consisting in Arduinos. After a first intruduction, I found it to be quite similar to C/C++. But since the group manager won't allow us to take them home, I'm stuck with only learning codes, and not using them.
My question is: Is there any 3-D software, or anything similar, that if i enter a sketch, it tells you what happened.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "similar to C/C++". It actually *is* C++. The Arduino IDE just hides most of the complexity from you.

Comment: I thought it was C at first glance. But meh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Proteus VSM](http://www.labcenter.com/products/vsm/vsm_overview.cfm) will allow you to [simulate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP0OA-2bcxk) the AVR at the heart of the Arduino as well as a wide variety of peripherals, but at its price point you'll probably find it much cheaper to just buy a real AVR MCU or module, ISP programmer, breadboard, and components instead.

Comment: Thank you, it was very costy, but maybe I can convince the manager, who knows, or find another solution.